# How to insert value in a DataGridView from a DataSet based on data contained in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, dataset

I need to fill out a `DataGridView` that already contains a list of all the items. This based on movement records of materials contained in a `DataSet`. The `DataGridView` already has all items, for example: A, B, C, D, etc. And the program will check the current balance of each item based on movements of a stock contained in the `DataSet`.

I thought to do a foreach inside the other. The `DataGridView` out line by line to find the name of the item and the other internal foreach makes the search in dataSet where the movement of a stock are recorded.

I made it this way, but it is filling only the first line of the `Balance` column.

```
void FillDataGrid()
{
    var result = 0;
    string strRowMaterial = string.Empty;

    Conection ca = new Conection();
    string sql = "";
    sql += " Select ";
    sql += " idRegMovement, CatMovement, NameMovement, codMaterial, AmountMovemented ";
    sql += " From RegMovement ";
    sql += " ORDER BY idRegMovement ";

    ca.Connect();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, ca.cx);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "RegMovements");
    if (ds.Tables["RegMovements"].Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        ca.Disconnect();
    }
    else
    {

        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in datagridview.Rows)
        {
            strRowMaterial = Convert.ToString(dr.Cells["codMaterial"].Value);

            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["RegMovements"].Rows)
            {
                if (string.Compare(row["codMaterial"].ToString(), strRowMaterial, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    var Amount = Convert.ToInt32(row["AmountMovemented"]);

                    if (string.Compare(row["CatMovement"].ToString(), "Input", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
                        result += Amount;

                    else
                        result -= Amount; 
                }
                else
                {
                    result = 0;
                }                        

            }
            datagridview.CurrentRow.Cells["Balance"].Value = result;
        }
    }
    ca.Disconnect();
}
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding the value you use only 1 row `CurrentRow`

```
datagridview.CurrentRow.Cells["Balance"].Value = result;
```

if you foreach through the:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in datagridview.Rows)
```

you should also use the variable:

```
dr.Cells["Balance"].Value = result;
```